# C# Docusign - Add signature elements to PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I'm fairly new to using Docusign (I have just created an account).  I'm curious if the following functionality exists.

I currently have an existing system that generates PDFs, but currently when the PDFs are generated for signing they are sent to an external vendor website/portal to have the docusign elements dealt with.

Each PDF that is generated by the system contains different information,so using templates via Docusign won't work.

I'm attempting to take a flat PDF file, and insert Docusign elements to be completed at a later time.  Is this something that Docusign can do, or how should I go about approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible *"to take a flat PDF file, and insert Docusign elements to be completed at a later time."*

- How should I go about approaching this?

See the Rest API Recipe [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email) for requesting a Signature using Docusign

This recipe allows you to supply a PDF document(or multiple documents) and supply [Tabs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) based on your requirements.

The [Docusign developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview) is a great place to start

**C# SDK:**

There is also a useful [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) to integrate DocuSign into your app.

Comment: Thank you for the link - but that doesn't quite address the question.  Can it be done from many different PDFs (not templates?) I'll still review the link a bit more

Comment: Yes it is possible to supply multiple PDF documents without using templates. The recipe I have provided shows how to supply a document and request a signature using Docusign. Please review it and post any specific questions you have.

Comment: "DocuSign to create an envelope with a single signer, and place one signature tab on the envelope's single document, located 100 pixels to the right and 100 pixels down from the top left of the document."

Does this support multiple signature points and pages of a PDF?

Comment: Yes you can specify multiple Signatures, Multiple pages and create complex signature workflows. YOu can also have multiple Signers if you need.

Comment: Thanks for all the great material - This will give me a great start.  I just didn't want to get too far, and realize Docusign didn't have this functionality.